# Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched in Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Herei'm going to take a values from ViewBag.But below error occured.

Specific Error Message is

> > Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'TextBox' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

ViewBag in Controller

```
 ViewBag.Vat = tx.GetVatDetails().FirstOrDefault().Percentage; // result is 15.0
```

In my View

```
 @Html.TextBox("vat",ViewBag.Vat); // in here that error occured
```

How do i solve this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will work :-

```
@Html.TextBox("vat",(float)ViewBag.Vat);  //Type cast `ViewBag` to float here
```

Casting of the `Viewbag` data to `float` worked because Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched and `Viewbag` is a `dynamic` `object` that is why we have to first typecast it into appropriate type which is `float` here.

Comment: Yes.It's a Float value.. i use (float)ViewBag.Vat  Solved.Thanks

Comment: Could you pls explain why do i need to cast here ?